# How can i replace this statement in ios5

Tags: iphone, ios

When i write ' stringWithContentsOfURL' i am getting error that 'stringWithContentsOfURL is Deprecated'.

```
    -(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation 
{
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
      [addressField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        double latitude = 0.0;
        double longitude = 0.0;

        if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
            latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
            longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
        }
        else {
            //Show error
        }
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
        location.latitude = latitude;
        location.longitude = longitude;

        return location;
    }
```

How can i replace this line. Thanks!

```
NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

Comment: You will probably need to replace that line with an asynchronous request followed immediately by a return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been replaced with

```
stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:
```

or

```
stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:
```

Example code

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSString* locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for stringWithContentsOfURL.  In the NSString documentation it tells you exactly what methods are used to replace that deprecated one, and its good to know how to do as checking the docs for this sort of stuff is something you'll do frequently.